# C++: possible Xcode (Mac) problem. Can't read in numbers from external file using getline()

Tags: c++, stream, streaming, getline

I'm a Mac Xcode (3.2.2) user, working with the GCC 4.2 compiler, fairly inexperienced with C++ and completely ignorant about compilers.

I need to read in numbers from an external file and store them in a vector of ints. I wrote code using streams and getline(). I can compile the code and it runs without errors, but there is no output. It works for a friend (non-Mac and non-GCC 4.2 compiler) though.

I did some googling and found several posts about a possible compiler (gcc, Apple) issue in Xcode 3.2.1 that might relate to my problem (this one, for example: C++ using getline() prints: pointer being freed was not allocated in XCode. However, I have Xcode 3.2.2. I tried the suggested fixes (related to adding _GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING to (1) the target settings window or (2) as preprocessor macros before the includes), but my problem is still not solved.

So I don't know what my problem is at this point--whether it is the same compiler issue that people had in Xcode 3.2.1 but a different fix is required in 3.2.2. Or if there is some other problem in my code.

It would be great if someone could offer some advice. No advice is too simple. If there is another way to import numbers from an external file, I would love to know about it. Also, does anyone know if there would be any reason it would be possible to import data from a .dat file, but not a .txt file on a Mac?

Thank you.

Since first posting, I have included wilhelmtell's edits.

Goal: Read numbers from a text file into a vector of ints called "results."

1) The data in the data file test.dat initially looked like,

//Test

test

'1' '2' '3'

// There are also labels and comments in the text file that I don't want to read in but can't delete from the file.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

// Edited: added struct (wilhelmtell's advice)
struct not_digit_and_not_whitespace {
    bool operator()(char c) const {
        return ! std::isdigit(c) && ! std::isspace(c);
    }
};

int main()
{
    system("pwd");

    std::string line;
    const std::string fileName = "/Users/me/test.dat";  

    ifstream theStream( fileName.c_str() ); 

    if( ! theStream )
          std::cerr << "Error opening file test.dat\n";

    std::getline( theStream, line );
    // line.erase(remove( line.begin(), line.end(), '\'' ), line.end() ); // Edited (wilhelmtell's advice)
    line.erase(remove_if( line.begin(), line.end(),not_digit_and_not_whitespace()), line.end() );  // Edited: added (wilhelmtell's advice)

    std::istringstream myStream( line );
    std::vector<int> numbers((std::istream_iterator<int>(myStream)), std::istream_iterator<int>());

    std::copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));

    /* int temp;  // Edited: wilhemtell suggested using iterators instead.
    while ( myStream >> temp ){
        numbers.push_back( temp );
     std::cout << temp << std::endl;
    }*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless you post the source code, at least around the area that the crash is occurring, I doubt that anyone can help you very much

Comment: I suspect it is outputting something, but not in the way you expect.  If you compile a "Hello World" program, can you see its output?

Comment: I made a Hello World and that worked, so I tried replacing the ints with strings in my original code (before I made wilhemtell's edits) and it reads in the "test" label just fine.  I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you.  It uses getline as you were trying, but uses the '\'' character to serve as the line delimiter.  Ignore everything up to the first '.  Assume everything until the next ' is part of a number.  Continue until the logic fails (presumably due to end of file).

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    system("pwd");

    std::string line;
    const std::string fileName = "test.dat";  

    std::ifstream theStream( fileName.c_str() ); 

    if( ! theStream )
          std::cerr << "Error opening file test.dat\n";

    std::vector<int> numbers;

    while (true)
    {
        // get first '
        std::getline(theStream, line, '\'');
        // read until second '
        std::getline(theStream, line, '\'');
        std::istringstream myStream( line );
        int i;
        myStream >> i;
        if (myStream.fail())
            break;
        numbers.push_back(i);
    }
    std::copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Comment: Howard, it worked!!!  Thank you so much.  I will now have to sit down and figure out why it works.  This has been driving me nuts.  I can't vote you up because I don't have enough reputation points.  Thanks to you and wilelmtell for being so patient and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your test.dat file is not in the working directory. To verify that you can test the stream:

```
if( ! theStream )
    std::cerr << "Error opening file test.dat\n";
```

Check your project properties in XCode to see what the working directory is, and place the file there.

If your file contains data that doesn't parse as integers then the streams' `int` parsing will fail. Make sure the line you read has nothing but integers and whitespace:

```
#include <cctype>  // algorithm iterator ...

struct not_digit_and_not_whitespace {
    bool operator()(char c) const {
        return ! std::isdigit(c) && ! std::isspace(c);
    }
};

// ...
line.erase(remove_if( line.begin(), line.end(),
                     not_digit_and_not_whitespace()),
           line.end() );
```

Also, you can simplify your code. First, if you include `<iostream>` then you don't need `<istream>`. Secondly, you can use the range constructor of `std::vector` to get the integers.

```
#include <algorithm>  // iterator fstream iostream vector string sstream

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream theStream("test.dat");
    std::getline(theStream, line);
    line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\'' ),
               line.end());
    std::istringstream myStream(line);
    std::vector<int> numbers((std::istream_iterator<int>(myStream)),
                             std::istream_iterator<int>());
    std::copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @wilhelmtell, I did that.  I edited the code I posted for pwd.  I put my data file in my home directory.  The output of the code is pwd, but it still does not work.  Thanks and thanks for the simplification tips.

Comment: Who is the owner of the file? What are the permission bits? Did you try to add the test for the stream like I suggested above?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the delay.  Had some errors to work out.  I did change it to what you suggested (I'll edit the code I posted in a second).  It still does not work (if I implemented your corrections correctly).  I own the file.

Comment: Did I add the if( ! theStream ) code in the right place (see edited code above)?  When I compile and run the code, nothing happens.  It is the same as before.  Should the test.dat file pop open?

Comment: Check the stream right after construction, before touching it with `std::getline()`. Although if you don't see the error now then I presume the file opened. Also, show us the contents of the file test.dat, please.

Comment: The test file?  I can't get things on different lines in this comment.  In the file, //Test, test, and the numbers are on different lines.  It will look much more complicated when I have real data in the file.                                                   //TEST
test 
'1' '2' '3' '4'

Comment: I did check the stream right after construction.  Nothing has changed.  I will edit the code I posted in a second.  Thanks for being so patient.

Comment: P.S. When I was searching online I saw a post where someone's code started running when the file had spaces removed after the data.  So I did that in my file.  There are no spaces or anything after the symbols.

Comment: Your file contains characters that don't parse as integers, that's the issue. I updated my answer. Let me know if this resolves your issue.

Comment: @wilhelmtell, do you mean that there should be nothing in the text file except for numbers and white-space?  The symbols that separate the numbers should be removed?

Comment: No, what I mean is that if you parse characters from a stream as an `int`, then the extraction operator which does the parsing expects digits only, since integers compose of digits and only digits. Whitespace are allowed, to delimit integers. So when you read the file into a `std::istringsteam` you need to make sure you only feed digits and whitespace to the stream. To this effect I updated your remove/erase call.

Comment: @wilhelmtell, thanks for all your help.  I added your edits to the code posted.  Still doesn't work!!  I can delete the delimiter symbols between the numbers, but I have to have labels (like test) and comments (like //Test).  The file is output from another code and I can't change that.  Your help is really appreciated.  The original code worked when I gave it to friends who don't use Macs.  I'll be back in a few hours.  Thanks.

Comment: In your original remove/erase, you only removed apostrophes. But you showed me the contents of the file, and clearly the file has characters other than apostrophes, digits and whitespace. Specifically, it starts with `//TEST test` and when you try to parse _that_ as integers clearly that is going to fail. You want to remove more than just apostrophes. You want to remove _anything_ that isn't a digit and isn't whitespace.

Comment: Now I understand.  Thanks so much.  I would not have even known that that would be a problem or how to deal with it.  I edited the post again and tested the code.  It still doesn't work!